# Tests not executing continuously on grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Below is way how I started Hub

```
java\bin\java.exe -cp .\lib\* -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=drivers\IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=drivers\geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=drivers\chromedriver.exe org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role hub
```

And node is started as

```
java\bin\java.exe -cp .\lib\* -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=drivers\IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=drivers\geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=drivers\chromedriver.exe org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser "browserName=internet explorer, maxInstances=5" -browser "browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5" -browser "browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5"
```

I have TestNG.xml file with around 20 test cases. I started execution on grid. Execution is good and all tests are executing but I am facing small issue.

Execution is started and executed say around 10 tests then waiting around 15-20min and then executing remaining test cases…like that. I am bit not sure way its waited for some time in between execution?

This waiting is not related to wait commands in scripts, my test case is completely executed and browser of that test case is closed and then new browser has to open for another test case. Here its waiting. After some time executions are goes on then after its wait after some time.

Comment: are you running it parallel? how  many parallel threads you have?

Comment: Yes, running parallel with 2 methods usually i.e. 2 browsers opens at a time. tried 5, 10  and even 1 also.

Comment: You are on SeleniumGridv2 or SeleniumGridv3?

Comment: Grid3 all are latest version jars

Answer (score 0):

Lack of free instances to work with. You said there are 20 test cases and executing 10 then waiting. These kinds of waits happen in Grid when there are lack of free instances. You could try to take a look at Selenium Grid Extras. It can help such situations.

Comment: the number of test cases i provided is just for as example. is there any way can i found whats issues here in grid instead of extras?

Comment: Can you post the log? It would be easier to go from there. From what I can grasp from your question, it appears that the node is actually waiting for an instance to complete before moving to the next one. Whatever wait time you are looking at is actually the node trying to wait for an instance to finish. If you could post some logs, it would be easier to take it ahead.

Comment: in grid can we get logs?, else i need to try grid extras.

Comment: Nope, people usually write their own logging servlet. Dump the logs into a folder and check it from there. Its customization at your end. Look for custom servlets for selenium grid shared by other guys.

Comment: sure, i will look and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.

Actually here is two reasons why driver is waiting in between the execution instead of continuously executing all tests.

1. I missed driver.quit(); i started driver, set to local thread, once test is done, closed driver and removed the thread. As driver.quit is not used, so slot is not freed-up for another node, Now used driver.quit to free up the slot for another node
2. Used -timeout 30 when starting the hub. In any case if slot is not free up for node and if we not mention -timeout 30 then by default 1800 sec taken as timeout to free slot for node. Which is very high time.